# Mocha/Chai TypeError: Cannot read property 'include' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, should.js

So I have this super simple Chai test that keeps failing for reasons I don't understand. Here is my code:

```js
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const helpers = require('../lib/helpers.js');
let chai = require('chai');

let should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Helper Functions', () => {
    it('it should return an array of objects that represent the URL parameters passed in', function() {
        const requestURL = {url: '/?designID=54w9G44aphaNHTvKg&labels=true&props=true'};
        let parameters = helpers.getQueryParameters(requestURL);

        (parameters).should.include.keys(['designID', 'labels', 'props']);
        (parameters.designID).should.be.eql('54w9G44aphaNHTvKg');
        (parameters.labels).should.be.eql('true');
        (parameters.props).should.be.eql('true');
    });
});
```

Everytime i try to test, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'include' of undefined`

If i comment out `(parameters).should.include.keys(['designID', 'labels', 'props']);`, eveything passes. I haven't the slightest idea what is causing this...

When i console.log parameters, this is the object returned:

```js
{
    designID: '54w9G44aphaNHTvKg',
    labels: 'true',
    props: 'true'
}
```

**UPDATE**

So when i change the line to:

```js
(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parameters))).should.have.keys(['designID', 'labels', 'props']);
```

Everything works fine... is there some kind of feature/bug that doesn't allow chai to read JSON unless it's properly formatted with double quotes?

Comment: It is not JSON with it's properly formatted double quotes.

Comment: @AdrianBrand So everytime i want to check the keys of my object, i have to do that JSON.parse JSON.stringify stuff? That seems like overkill..